# Exception: Event start time must be before event end time. (line 15, file "CreateEvent") error adding event to calendar via Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

The code is as below, on running the same I am getting the following error :-

Exception: Event start time must be before event end time. (line 15, file "CreateEvent")

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('E4').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:C10").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups[x];

    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var title = shift[2];

  eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
  }
}

function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule shifts Now', 'CreateShifts')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: check the supported date format, might be your date is in diffrent format, first convert into expected format , and then add to calendar event.

Comment: It would help others if you can also share a sample of the spreadsheet that others can use to reproduce the error that you are getting. Without being able to reproduce the error, it would not be possible for others to provide a correct response, and end up in speculating what the error might be.

Comment: To better understand the issue can you share the sheet data? The date formatting will help in investigating the issue.

If the date formats are correct, you might have the order mixed up. The startTime should be a date in the past and the endTime should be a present or future set;

Answer (score 0):

```js
function scheduleShifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('E4').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:C10").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups[x];

    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[0];
    var title = shift[2];

  eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
  }
}

function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule shifts Now', 'CreateShifts')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).